# 10,100,200,300... is not working while testing

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I need to get a number from user,and seprate them into single digit and store it into data structure without inserting any of the number which is already inserted.

My program works fine for number which gives some remainder , but it doesn't  work for the number which gives the remainder zero.

For now I din make my code dynamic , I just tested by changing the of  **i**

And my code goes like this:

```
public class Samp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 555,n;
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(i > 0) {
        n = i % 10;
        if(digits.contains(n)){
            break;
        }else{
            digits.add(n);
        }
        i /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(digits);
}
}
```

Please help me to write the code that works for all numbers.

Comment: This algorithm will only ever produce 1 number. What series are trying to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList` if you are looking to prevent duplicates.

You can simply start putting the values in the `HashSet`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 555;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    while(i > 0) {
        set.add(i % 10);
        i /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Output:

```
[5]
```

Comment: surely a more elegant solution than using a List, but why the change from Integer to Character?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Yes, you are absolutely right. I changed it to `Integer`. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: @user2004685 Thats working well , i am new to java and i don't know about  **HashSet**  . if you don't mind can you please explain me the code you have done?

Comment: @AkashPreet `HashSet` is just like `HashMap`. It does not allow duplicates. So, if `5` is already present in the `HashSet` then no matter how many times you add `5` to it, you'll still get exactly one `5`. `ArrayList` on the other hand is ordered list which allows duplicate entries. As per your requirements `HashSet` is suited here.

Comment: @AkashPreet I'm using the same code which you have written. It's just that I'm not checking whether set contains the digit or not as this check is not needed with `HashSet`. I have explained the reason above.

Comment: @user2004685 Thank you so much for spending your time with my problem. And I understand what is **HashSet ** now .

Comment: @AkashPreet Your Welcome! :) Please accept the answer by clicking the greyed out right click button just below the voting counter if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn´t work in general, because you `break` out of the loop once it found a duplicate digit. just remove the unnecessary `break`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5000, n;
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (i > 0) {
        n = i % 10;
        if (!digits.contains(n)) {
            digits.add(n);
        }
        i /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(digits);
}
```

output:

```
[0, 5]
```